# Displaying an error: “Original error: ‘app’ option is required for reinstall” while start session in Appium

Tags: android, android-studio, appium, desiredcapabilities

I’m new at Appium.
I defined into ‘`Desired Capabilities`’ tab needed capabilities such as:

- deviceName
- udid
- platformName
- platformVersion
- appPackage
- appActivity

After I clicked on the `Start Session` button, I got the error message `“An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: ‘app’ option is required for reinstall”.`

Before that, I started a virtual android device but I don't have the right app on my device. Should I connect source code with Appium capabilities and how do I do that? Which tools should be used (Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA)?

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when you don't have an app installed on your device.

Two ways to resolved this issue-:

1. Install the application on the device using a script by using app capabilities.

   In the app's desired capability, you have to give an absolute path for the `.apk` file.

   ```
   "platform"       : "Android",               
   "platformVersion": "9.0",
   "deviceName"     : "Redmi Nitin",
   "appPackage".    : "my.nitin.stackoverflow",
   "appActivity"    : "view.activity.splash.SplashScreenActivity",
   "automationName" : "uiautomator2",
   "app".           : "giveherepath.apk"
   "fullReset".     : "true"
   ```
2. If you don't want to install the `.apk` file using script then you install it manually and launch the app using package name and activity capabilities as you mention in question.

   ```
   "platform"       : "Android",               
   "platformVersion": "9.0",
   "deviceName"     : "Redmi Nitin",
   "appPackage".    : "my.nitin.stackoverflow",
   "appActivity"    : "view.activity.splash.SplashScreenActivity",
   "automationName" : "uiautomator2",
   "fullReset".     : "true"
   ```

Comment: I fixed the issue. All I had to do was to build an apk in the source code and drag and drop on my Android Virtual Device. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MajaUcek Great. We can drag and drop for manual installation of .apk file,

Comment: For me it was wrong 'appPackage'. Changing it to my app's correct package value solved it.